# Pure HTML Back Button

Tags: html

I want to create a Page Back Button using HTML & CSS Without using Javascript or any other language. I want to do it in pure HTML & CSS.

I searched but didn't get any solution every time javascript is included in code but I need a pure HTML no any other language.

Comment: that's not possible, you'll need some `JavaScript` or better accomplish the task while rendering the page by the server side's language (`PHP` for example).

Answer (score 11):

You can do it "without using JavaScript" just in case the previous page is known in advance, *i.e.* you are in a "detail" page and the "back" button will bring you to the "list" or home page, *e.g.*:

```
<a href="home">Back</a>
```

Else, if the previous page changes dynamically you need to use JavaScript [`history.back`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp) method:

```
<a href="javascript:window.history.back();">Back</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for you time & consideration but it changes dynamically

Comment: It should be `<a href="javascript:window.history.back();">Back</a>` (note the `javascript:`). Without the `javascript:` it will simply take you to a page whose URL is `window.history.back();`, which will often result in a 404 error.

Comment: I know this is not the answer to the question but it *is* the code I was looking for (+1).

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, can't be done. HTML was designed to markup your content semantically, indicating what is a heading, what is text, etc. It knows nothing about the container that is displaying it, which may not necessarily be a browser.

CSS was designed to make the HTML look good. It is used for placing elements in the container, as well as suggesting how they look (colour, size, etc). Other than a few extras added to allow you to style the scrollbars etc, it also knows nothing about the container, and so cannot affect behaviour.

Why do you want to do this? JavaScript was designed for this purpose, why try and avoid it?

Answer (score 4):

The following piece of code doesn't require any javascript file, but still uses javascript inside html :

```html
<a href="javascript:history.back()">Back to previous page</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML is the Template, CSS is the Style.
JavaScript gives logic to your elements. 
It is essential for every dynamic action in your page.

To answer your question you cannot achieve it without it.

Answer (score 2):

No way. The only code in pure html involves also javascript:

```
<input type="button" value="back" onclick="history.back()"/>
```

No CSS needed.

Answer (score 2):

When you want the back button to go exactly one level back in the URL tree, you can use the following code:

```
<a href="../"><input type="button" value="Back"/></a>
```

Append multiple `../` to go multiple steps back in the URL tree.

No Javascript is required to do this.

Comment: It doesn't jump to the previous page but to the previous directory 

Answer (score 1):

For Going to previous page

```
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Go Back</a>
```